# symmetric and asymmetric encryption between Angular 2 and Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, encryption

I need send a password from Angular App to Spring boot backend and i need encrypt this password. I try to use AES to encrypt the password and RSA to encrypt the AES generated key, but i dont know how do this. 
My code:
Angular 2 Side:

EncryptService:

```
public generateRandomKey( keyLength: number){
    let chars =
`0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmn
opqrstuvwxyz*&-%/!?*+=()`;
    let stringKey = "";
    for (let i=0; i < keyLength; i++) {
      var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
      stringKey += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }

    return stringKey;

  }

  public aesEncrypt( phrase: string ){
    let key = this.generateRandomKey(50);
    let aesEncrypt = cryptojs.AES.encrypt(phrase, key);
    let aesKey = aesEncrypt.key
    let aesIv = aesEncrypt.iv;
    let encryptMessage = aesEncrypt.toString();

    return [encryptMessage, aesKey, aesIv];
  }


  public buildPubkFromPem( pem: string ){
    return forge.pki.publicKeyFromPem(pem);
  }
```

Component:

```
let pubKey = this.encryptService.buildPubkFromPem(environment.publicKey);
let data = this.encryptService.aesEncrypt(map.passwd);
let passwdEncrypt = data[0];
let aesKey = data[1];
let encryptAesKey = pubKey.encrypt(aesKey.toString());

      this.pendingRequestService
          .send({'passwd': passwdEncrypt, 'encryptAesKey': encryptAesKey)
          .finally(()=>{this.popupSignService.isLoading = false;})
          .subscribe( 
            result => {
              console.log("OK", result);
            }
        );
    }
```

Backend Side:
Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity signDocs(
            @RequestParam(value = "passwd") String              passwd,
            @RequestParam(value = "encryptAesKey") String       encryptAesKey,
    ){

        try{
            signatureService.decryptMessage(passwd, encryptAesKey);
        }catch( Exception ex ){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Service:

```
public String decryptMessage( String encrypMsg, String encryptAesKey ){

        // Load private key from P12
        ClassPathResource pkcs12     = new ClassPathResource("ssl/file.p12");
        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(pkcs12.getInputStream(), p12Password.toCharArray());
        String          alias   =   (String)keystore.aliases().nextElement();

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) keystore.getKey(alias, p12Password.toCharArray());

        // Decrypt
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        System.out.println(encryptAesKey);
        byte[] doFinal = cipher.doFinal(encryptAesKey.getBytes());
        String aesKey = new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encryptAesKey)), "UTF-8");

        return aesKey;

    }
```

when i try to decrypt the AES encrypted key:

```
javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes
```

I think it's related when I encrypted the AES key.
Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

If i encrypt the string "Some text" with the public key using forge, and send the encrypted text to the backend does not work. If i ecrypt and decrypt using the same public and private key work from javascript to javascript and java to java.
Javascript code:

```
let encryptedText = pubKey.encrypt(this.forgeService.encodeUTF8("Some text"));//<-- Encrypt "Some text"
```

I dont know if something is loosing (changing) when i send the encrypted text in the network.

Comment: If this is just transport encryption (not end-to-end, your server is decrypting it after all), why not just use HTTPS?

Comment: @Thilo For schoolar reasons i need to do this.

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have basic problem with encoding data (along others)

`let encryptAesKey = pubKey.encrypt(aesKey.toString());`

You are encrypting string representation of the key (not the key itself) and I believe JS returns the toString() in the hex format (please correct  me if I am wrong). The result would be twice as long as the original key.

while i Java you are trying to decrypt the encrypted hex string rssulting in a byte array, which doesn't fit into expected 256 bit size

edit:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
cipher.init(Cipher.PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
```

is wrong, you have to use Cipher. DECRYPT_MODE.

next :

`String aesKey = new String(cipher.doFinal(..` DO NOT make a string from the key (encode when you want to print it), keep it as byte array. You are loosing nonprintable values.

you should be specific with the encryption mode

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("rsa/ecb/nopadding");
```

Comment: Thanks for yor answer, but if i simply encrypt the short text "Some text", and send it to the backend does not work either. If i try javascript -> javascript and java -> java work. I edit my question.